# "Waiting list" vs. "wait list", "visiting card" vs. "visit card"

Tags: word-choice, present-participles

Should one say "I’ll put you on the waiting list" or "on the wait list"? Likewise, is it "I will give you my visiting card" or "my visit card"?

I am very confused when to use the *-ing* form or not. Is there a general rule?

Comment: _In general_ (although there may be exceptions), both are acceptable, since the "ing" form (gerund) is the noun denoting the act of doing the verb. You may be interested in [ell.se](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) also.

Comment: Using "wait list" just sounds wrong and awkward. It's normally *waiting list*.

Comment: But _waitlist_ has become common as the verb form, as in "I applied to So-and-so University, but I was waitlisted".

Comment: I'm a Government of Canada employee, and I've recently noticed that the HR letters we send to competition participants use 'wait list', but I've always said 'waiting list'.

Answer (score 5):

"I'll put you on the waiting list" - US & UK. Slightly commoner in UK than in US.

"I'll put you on the wait list" - Almost exclusively US; much rarer than 'waiting list'.

(Data source: Google Ngram viewer; corpuses: British English 2009, American English 2009)

Are you sure you mean *visiting card* (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visiting_card ) rather than *business card?*

But -- since you asked -- *visiting card* is the usual term.

I don't think there is a general rule for the use of *-ing* versus no *-ing*, except that British English tends not to drop it. However, it is much safer to treat the various expressions where it might or might not be used on a case-by-case basis, and to just try to remember which version is idiomatic.

Comment: +1 but I want to point out that "wait list" is *extremely* rare and I'm not sure if I've ever heard it used with "on" as in your example. I recommend avoiding the term completely.

Comment: @MrHen First time I heard it used over an airport tannoy in America I thought it was spelled 'weight list', and had something to do with the fact that some small airlines with tiny planes weighed the passengers and their luggage together.

Comment: @MrHen - I suspect (without having researched it) that the noun "wait list" is a back-formation from the verb "to waitlist".

Answer (score -1):

Citing “cat food,” “book store,” and “web site,” is like comparing apples to oranges. Those cited words are compound nouns, where the name of the thing is more than one word. Those are not nouns modifying nouns. For example, you wouldn’t say, “stand ovation” for “standing ovation,” or “walk wounded” for “walking wounded.”

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the person asking, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer. Expert partial answers are welcome, but notions, trial balloons, offhand ideas, guesses, anecdotes, and general discussion are not answers.

Comment: Where, though, did you get the idea that anyone might use "wait list", let alone "visit card"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_list

Answer (score -2):

It should be “waiting list,” not “wait list.” It is improper to modify a noun with another noun, or a verb, for that matter. We learned in grammar school that a participle substitutes for an adjective.

Comment: “It is improper to modify a noun with another noun…” Ever heard of “cat food” or a “book store” (not to mention a “web site”)?

Comment: @Scott A 'cauliflowering ear' doesn't seem too idiomatic either.